# Running an IRC bot under current nick?

Tags: bots, irc

I'm developing my own [irc](/questions/tagged/irc) bot and in a channel I'm in, one of the ops is able to activate a bot but run it under his own nick without a new nick joining the channel.

For example, guy's nick is `@James` and he activated a bot that says hello when you do `.hello`:

```
+John: .hello
@James: Hello, John.
```

Any idea how is this done possibly? The only way I've been able to run my bot is to connect it to the server & channel with a completely new nick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really depends on how the bot is written/implemented. Some IRC clients (like [MIRC](http://www.mirc.com/) or [HexChat/X-Chat](http://hexchat.github.io/)) support scripting. As such you're able to extend them to act just like bots even though someone is actually using them as a standard client. I could also imagine some interface being use, like a bouncer, which allows multiple clients to connect to one permanent IRC session.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways

eggdrops
or mIRCScripting

script like on texts, can't be triggered by yourself

example

```
 on $*:text:/^\.h(i|ello)$/iS:#:{
   msg $chan $+(h,$regml(1)) $nick
 }
```

the difference is, when you run your bot on the same mIRC client
you can specify who is the owner of the bot, and who is not

like

```
on $*:text:/^\.h(i|ello)$/iS:#:{
    if ($me == botname) {
   msg $chan $+(h,$regml(1)) $nick
 }
}
```

the script will only trigger, if it is running under Bot's name